# How to add placeholder UserCreationForm django?

Tags: django

I'm trying to add a placeholder to the username field in the UserCreationForm
but i can't understand how to do it.
I have already change the forms.py file in this way /lib/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py.

I add a placeholder to password1 and password2 fields and work like this:

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
"""
A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
password.
"""
error_messages = {
    'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
}
password1 = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Password"),
    strip=False,
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password'}),
    help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
)
password2 = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Password confirmation"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Confirmar Password'}),
    strip=False,
    help_text=_("Enter the same password as before, for verification."),
)
```

I can see probably the username field is coming from class meta:

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username",)
    field_classes = {'username': UsernameField}
```

from this class but i'm not sure about that

```
class UsernameField(forms.CharField):
def to_python(self, value):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', super().to_python(value))
```

I don't understand how add a placeholder to username field

this is my html

```
<form method="post" action=".">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    {% for field in form %}
                        {{ field }}<br />
                        {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
                        {% endfor %} 
                    {% endfor %}
                <input id="submit-signup-btn" type="submit" value="Iniciar"/>    
            </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

After a while looking at this, i found a way to do it, this is the way i did it:

in the file /lib/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py, in class UserCreationForm, under class Meta there is a **init** function where you can see this line

```
self.fields[self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': 
True})
```

i added the placeholder to the end of the line in the update method like this:

```
self.fields[self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': True,
                                                                          'placeholder':'Nome Perfil'})
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Gabriel costa answer, I came up with this solution:

```
class AccountCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder':_('Username')})
    self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder':_('Email')})
    self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder':_('Password')})        
    self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder':_('Repeat password')})
```

Other solutions don't work in this scenario.

Comment: why the ```_``` before every placeholder?

Comment: Oh, sorry the "_" is a placeholder for gettext function used in translation. You don't need to use that. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar problem before, this is how i solved it :

```
class Meta:
   ......
   widgets = {
    'username': forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'random stuff'})
}
```

or internally , e.g

```
city = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'text'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define widgets in form's Meta class.

```
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username",)
    field_classes = {'username': UsernameField}
    widgets = {
        'username': form.fields.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your text for placeholder'})
    }
```