# Adding placeholder to UserCreationForm in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I want to add placeholders to the UserCreationForm in Django.

I'm a bit confused, because when I search for this topic I only find stuff [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53243932/how-to-add-placeholder-usercreationform-django) with complicated answers, where people suggest to change the **/lib/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py**. Isn't it an awful idea to change the code of Django itself?

Couldn't you just create a custom form like this, when you add placeholders to the authenticationForm:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, TextInput


class CustomAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class':'validate','placeholder': 'Email'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Password'}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show you how you do it for the [UserCreationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm)

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = ('username','password1','password2',)
        widgets = {
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                        'class':'form-control',
                        'placeholder':'Username here',
                }), 

        }
```

First of all , we import the default userCreationForm and the default user model.
Then , we create a custom **[ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)** named SignUpForm (or any descriptive name u can think of ! ) with a parent class (yep u guessed it) the UserCreationForm .

Now, as a modelForm we need to define a model which in our case is the default User we've imported .

Then, all you need is to define which fields you want to display, ([You can discover available fields here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) )

Now the most important part of your question, the placeholder. (Or any other attribute actually ;) )

You can do it simply by defining a widgets dictionnary , which contains the field name as a key , and the field type as a value.

for my example the key is the username field , and the value is

```
forms.TextInput()
```

What this line actualy does is converts the given field to an HTML input element to give it access to all possible attributes of that input (placeholder, class, id, maxlength etc..) .But how?

Well, just add an `attrs` dictionnary inside of the TextInput , define the attribute name as a key and the attribute value as the dictionnary value as shown in:

```
'placeholder' : 'Username here..',
```

This is if You want to create a Register/singup form .
But for a login form, I advise you to avoid headaches and just use an html form, bring the data in the views by `request.Get` and then authenticate your user .

Hope you find it useful !
Peace.

Comment: Thank you!! I really appreciate the explanation!! Only thing is, this makes the input field go very long

Comment: Glad u find it useful !
But Can't get what u mean by "very long"

Comment: Just had to remove the ```"class-form":"form-control"```. Now it isn't this huge

Comment: Oh ! Yeah that wasn't really part of the answer XD !
I just wanted to show you that you can include as much attributes as you wish!
Peace :)

Comment: @Saifeddin, I'm doing the exact same thing but the placeholders do not show up and I can't figure out why. Can you help? This is my form: https://pastebin.com/BiFWfuRq